# Bulk License Office 365 Users by OU with PowerShell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I'm trying to do something that I don't think should be too complicated of a fix. My end goal: I have certain users in one AD OU that need to use a certain license in Office 365, and different users in a different OU that get a different license.

The command that I'd like to run is:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=test,dc=our,dc=domain,dc=edu" | Set-MsolUserLicense -AddLicenses ourorg:STANDARDWOFFPACK_IW_STUDENT
```

but that fails with a response of:

`Set-MsolUserLicense : The input object cannot be bound because it did not contain the information required to bind all mandatory parameters:  ObjectId At line:1 char:111 + Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=Test students,ou=Students,dc=campus,dc=org,dc=edu" | Set-MsolUserLicense <<<<  -AddLicenses nwcu:STANDARDWOFFPACK_IW_STUDENT`

Individually, both of these commands work. I can select all users in the OU, and I can also manually use the Set-MsolUserLicense command with -UserPrincipalName to license a single user.

Is this because Get-ADUser doesn't return ObjectID like Set-MsolUserLicense is looking for? Get-ADUser does return ObjectGUID. If I'm on the right track here, is there a way to map these together for the piped input?

Edit: I'm aware the popular ways of doing this involve uploading a CSV file for this, and I know I could CSV-Export these users, but I already have them so neat and tidy in OUs, so I'd love to do this with now import/export if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although I don't know the syntax of the Set-MSOLUserLicense I'd suggest wrapping it in a for-each loop, e.g. `Get-ADUser | %{ Set-MSOLUserLicense -UserPrincipleName $_.UserPrincipalName }`

Comment: Interesting! So, that works! Just for fun, I also just tried Get-AdUser (limiting OU) | Set-MSOLUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName, but got an error back that it's null. It looks like the small for each loop is the way to go! Feel free to submit that as an answer. Excellent, simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkHenderson, I didn't want to just copy/paste your foreach example into my answer. If you want to edit or bless me doing so I'll update the answer.

Comment: @blaughw don't stress over it. Feel free to edit that script it. It's hardly proprietary stuff :) I'd edit it in but I'm not sure where you'd want me to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to use a for-each loop to enumerate each user and apply the license.  The loop needs to call up the `.UserPrincipalName` from each object returned in your `Get-ADUser` query, as Office365 needs to work with that value when setting licenses:

```
Get-ADUser | %{ Set-MSOLUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName }
```

I have created my own answer here to explain a common case that I think you're describing in your question:  You don't want to blanket apply the same license options to everyone.

[A TechNet Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/treycarlee/archive/2013/11/01/list-of-powershell-licensing-sku-s-for-office-365.aspx) on this matter is immensely helpful.  You may not want to give your Finance team access to SharePoint Online/OneDrive for Business for data leakage reasons, or you may have a call center who you don't want to enable for Lync/Skype for Business.

To get information on your tenant, start at the top:

`Get-MSOLAccountSku`

This will return the license packs you have in your tenant.  Some common SKUs are ENTERPRISEPACK and DESKLESSPACK.  These will be listed by `yourorg:LICENSEPACK` under AccountSkuId.

It is important to note that each of these License packs can have features disabled from them when you apply via PowerShell (similarly, you can choose to check/uncheck option boxes in the Admin Center).

[image: LicenseOptions]

To create this subset of license options, create a new variable and leverage the `New-MSOLLicenseOptions` cmdlet:
`$LicOpt = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId "yourorg:ENTERPRISEPACK" -DisabledPlans OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,MCOSTANDARD,SHAREPOINTWAC,SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE,RMS_S_ENTERPRISE`

(The above options would correspond to the screenshot above, I'm sure you could guess that I totally pulled it from a provisioning script.)

Finally, we can tie this back to your `Set-MsolUserLicense` in your ForEach loop:

```
$LicOpt = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId "yourorg:ENTERPRISEPACK" -DisabledPlans OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,MCOSTANDARD,SHAREPOINTWAC,SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE,RMS_S_ENTERPRISE

Get-ADUser | %{ Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses "yourorg:ENTERPRISEPACK" -LicenseOptions $LicOpt }
```

As always, your tenant may vary.  I hope I've given enough info for you to discover the options available and apply appropriately!